# Jersey proxy client can't deserialize JSON response to RAML generated classes

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-client, raml

I've generated classes with [raml-to-jaxrs maven plugin](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-for-jax-rs/tree/master/raml-to-jaxrs#using-the-maven-plugin) (2.1.1-SNAPSHOT) from [this RAML file](https://github.com/haba713/posti-smartship-client/blob/master/src/main/resources/root-resource-v1.raml) and call the service with Jersey proxy client like this:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
Feature feature = new LoggingFeature(logger, Level.INFO, null, null);
client.register(feature);        
client.register(new PostiSmartShipAuthenticator(username, password));
WebTarget target = client.target(URI);
Addresses proxy = WebResourceFactory.newResource(Addresses.class, target);
GetAddressesAgentsResponse response = proxy.getAddressesAgents("ITELLASP", null, "51270", null, "FI", null);
```

The service responds with an array of objects:

```
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > GET https://.../addresses/agents?type=ITELLASP&zip=51270&countryCode=FI
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Authorization: Basic ...

INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 200
1 < Connection: Keep-Alive
1 < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
1 < Date: Sun, 15 Oct 2017 10:38:53 GMT
1 < Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
1 < Server: Apache
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[{"id":"512053201","name":"Pakettiautomaatti, S-market Kangasniemi","address1":"Otto Mannisen tie 10","address2":null,"zipcode":"51205","city":"KANGASNIEMI","state":null,"countryCode":"FI","contact":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"email":null,"sms":null,"serviceType":null,"serviceCode":null,"openingHours":"ma-la 7.00 - 21.00, su 10.00 - 21.00"},{"id":"761053201","name":"Pakettiautomaatti, K-citymarket Pieksämäki","address1":"Kukkaroniementie 3","address2":null,"zipcode":"76105","city":"PIEKSÄMÄKI","state":null,"countryCode":"FI","contact":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"email":null,"sms":null,"serviceType":null,"serviceCode":null,"openingHours":"ma-pe 8.00 - 21.00, la 8.00 - 20.00, su 11.00 - 18.00"},{"id":"408053201","name":"Pakettiautomaatti, S-market Vaajala","address1":"Asematie 1","address2":null,"zipcode":"40805","city":"VAAJAKOSKI","state":null,"countryCode":"FI","contact":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"email":null,"sms":null,"serviceType":null,"serviceCode":null,"openingHours":"ma-la 7.00 - 22.00, su 10.00 - 22.00"},{"id":"409053201","name":"Pakettiautomaatti, S-market Säynätsalo","address1":"Parviaisentie 6","address2":null,"zipcode":"40905","city":"SÄYNÄTSALO","state":null,"countryCode":"FI","contact":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"email":null,"sms":null,"serviceType":null,"serviceCode":null,"openingHours":"ma-la 7.00 - 21.00, su 10.00 - 21.00"},{"id":"405253201","name":"Pakettiautomaatti, S-market Kuokkala","address1":"Syöttäjänkatu 2","address2":null,"zipcode":"40525","city":"JYVÄSKYLÄ","state":null,"countryCode":"FI","contact":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"email":null,"sms":null,"serviceType":null,"serviceCode":null,"openingHours":"ma-la 7.00 - 23.00, su 10.00 - 23.00"}]
```

However, the array of objects can not be deserialized to [GetAddressesAgentsResponse](https://github.com/haba713/posti-smartship-client/blob/master/src/main/java/haba713/postismartship/resources/Addresses.java#L39):

```
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't deserialize JSON array into: class haba713.postismartship.resources.Addresses$GetAddressesAgentsResponse
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.DeserializerBuilder.build(DeserializerBuilder.java:129)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:56)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:50)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:45)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:85)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonb.internal.JsonBindingProvider.readFrom(JsonBindingProvider.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:257)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1091)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:834)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:363)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:936)
... 37 more
```

For some reason the plugin seems to generate always classes with [com.fasterxml.jackson annotations](https://github.com/haba713/posti-smartship-client/blob/master/src/main/java/haba713/postismartship/model/Agent.java#L6) even though I have

```
<generateTypesWith>
    <value>jaxb</value>
</generateTypesWith>
```

in [pom.xml](https://github.com/haba713/posti-smartship-client/blob/master/pom.xml). Probably this is not the actual issue.

The effective dependencies currently are

```
javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.26
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.26
org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-proxy-client:2.26
org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.26
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:2.26
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-binding:2.26
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.26
org.raml.jaxrs:jaxrs-code-generator:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Should I use some other interface than Addresses here?

```
Addresses proxy = WebResourceFactory.newResource(Addresses.class, target);
```

What should be changed to make deserialization to work?

Kind regards,

Harri

Answer (score 0):

Are the model files annotated with jaxb Annotations ? (i.e: @XmlRootElement )

Comment: I use ["jaxb" in pom.xml](https://github.com/haba713/posti-smartship-client/blob/master/pom.xml#L136) but for some reason [the model files](https://github.com/haba713/posti-smartship-client/tree/master/src/main/java/haba713/postismartship/model) have Jackson annotations.

Comment: Well, I just looked at your project and you seem to be using jsonschema to describe your objects.  It will, of course, be mapped to json.  

The jaxb annotations will only be added to raml defined objects.

If you want to generate jaxb annotations from a schema (like the old raml 0.8 times), you will have to use xml schema.